# Pinging whole network to find devices

Tags: java, android, networking, arduino

I'm trying to ping local network from `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255` on 5000 port and an Arduino board is also connected to the network with 5000 port. I have Mac address of board and trying to find IP address. this is my code

```
static void pingLocal() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        ping("192.168.1." + i + ":5000");
    }
}

private static void ping(String url) {
    try {
        Process mIpAddrProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + url);
        int mExitValue = mIpAddrProcess.waitFor();
        System.out.println(" mExitValue " + mExitValue);
        if (mExitValue == 0) {
            Log.d("log", "true");
        } else {
            Log.d("log", "false");
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static String getIPFromArpCache(String mac) {
    if (mac == null)
        return null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("line", line);
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            if (splitted.length >= 4 && mac.equals(splitted[3])) {
                String ip = splitted[0];
                if (ip.split(".").length == 4) {
                    return ip;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            assert br != null;
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is the result

```
02-20 19:57:07.465 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
02-20 19:57:07.466 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.33     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.466 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.26     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.467 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.19     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.467 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.12     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.467 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.31     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.468 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.24     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.468 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.17     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.469 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.10     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.470 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.29     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.470 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.22     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.470 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.15     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.471 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.8      0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.471 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.1      0x1         0x2         c0:a0:bb:9a:e4:ad     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.472 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.27     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.472 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.20     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.472 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.13     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.473 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.32     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.473 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.25     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.473 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.18     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.474 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.11     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.474 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.30     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.475 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.23     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.475 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.16     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.475 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.9      0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.476 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.28     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.476 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.21     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
02-20 19:57:07.477 12103-12103/ir.shafadoc.handset D/line: 192.168.1.14     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
```

as you can see only modem has Mac address in arp cache. what is wrong? how can I discover network and find IP address from Mac?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What are you expecting?

Comment: My boards Mac address should be appeared in arp cache @zed

Comment: Which IP address is it? Does it appear in this log?

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which doesn't have ports. Ports are addresses for _some_ layer-4 protocols (TCP, UDP). ICMP acts like a layer-4 protocol, but it is actually part of IP, a layer-3 protocol, and it knows nothing about ports.

Comment: I don't know the IP address. the whole thing I'm trying to do is to find IP address from arp cache using Mac address. and no the Mac address of board isn't in the log @zed

Comment: so how can I do that? remove the port from IP address I'm pinging? because I did that and I didn't get result I expected. also it takes too long to ping all of IP addresses @RonMaupin

Comment: Continuing to what @RonMaupin said, make sure your board is pingable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method to ping the network and it's working perfect

```
if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
      System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
}
```